# Update Design Automation Rate Limit for Inventor Engine in APS

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation, autodesk-inventor

The default Inventor engine max rate limit is **900** as given in:

https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/rate-limits/da-rate-limits/

Since it's defined by the attribute `limitProcessingTimeSec`, I would like to understand where do we exactly set the rate limit attribute?

Here it says it has to be at the POST method while defining the workitem:

https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/reference/http/workitems-POST/

But where do we exactly set the curl? Any example is appreciated.

This is the Quotas tag within Job information found in output log:

```
"Quotas": {
"limitProcessingTimeSec": 900,
"limitTotalUncompressedAppsSizeInMB": 500 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `limitProcessingTimeSec` rate limit attribute is a part of the **WorkItem** class from **Autodesk.Forge.DesignAutomation.Model**:

```
public static WorkItem AsWorkItem(this WorkItemDataBundle bundle, string activityId, IBucketObject input, IBucketObject output) => new()
{
    ActivityId = activityId,
    Arguments = bundle.WorkItemArguments(input, output),
    LimitProcessingTimeSec = 1800 // Custom limit value
};
```

Answer (score 0):

limitProcessingTimeSec can be changed to a bigger value by the endpoint below. Please check the help document for more details. While if your workitem spends majority time on downloading and uploading data, you may consider to choose a cloud storage that is relatively close to APS. Or take advantage of APS bucket as the storage and sync with your storage/server after data is available.

https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/reference/http/servicelimits-owner-PUT/